# Get access to a public object from another Android application

Tags: java, android, android-security

Is it in any way possible that a public class or any of its public (static) method/public variable gets accessed/called by another application, given that the latter application has the source code of the first one?

Or at least, maybe on rooted devices, is it possible to determine their values from the ram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To conclude this I would first point out some basics:

- **Private** - Accessible within class
- **Protected** - Accessible from any class of the same package
- **Public** - Accessible from any class from any package.

Now if you have code of the first app and if you would add that in your libs folder then you would be able to access it at code level. But if you meant to get some value at run time like app 1 is running and if you want to access some methods from app2 then it won't be allowed as every app runs as a sandbox and in different process having unique id. So this is only possible at code level but not at runtime.

PS : No idea if you have rooted the phone. May be there would be some approach.